# Correct labeling of submenus

Tags: accessibility, uiaccessibility

For accessibility, what is the best/correct aria-label of a submenu. Should there be a general label followed by the purpose of the menu? Or should the aria-label be the same for all submenus?

Example: The image shows an example menu for book settings. When the user focus the menu trigger button. should the aria-label be: "submenu book settings" or just "submenu".
[image: Example menu]

Open for suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you are using [`aria-haspopup="true"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-haspopup).  Having that attribute will already notify the screen reader user that you have a submenu.  Different screen readers might announce it differently but the gist of it is that there's a submenu so you don't have to include that in your `aria-label`.  You can just have `aria-label="book settings"`.

Note, however, if you use `aria-haspopup`, then you are committing to supporting up/down arrow key navigation through your menu, rather than <kbd>tabbing</kbd> through the submenu list. See an example of the [menu button pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/example-index/menu-button/menu-button-links.html).

Alternatively, instead of using `aria-haspopup`, you could use `aria-expanded`.  You can support either tabbing through the submenu or arrowing up/down through the submenu, or both.  See the [Disclosure Navigation Menu example](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/example-index/disclosure/disclosure-navigation.html).  With `aria-expanded`, the screen reader will hear "collapsed" when they navigate to the 3-dots icon so they'll know they can press enter/space to expand the menu so, again, you don't need to say "submenu" in your `aria-label`.

Comment: Thank you :) In my case im using angular material that has keyboard support and aria-haspopup = true. I like «book settings», short and no unnecessary word.